# Hive : Optimize a long running Query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-tez

A simple Hive SQL query run on a 50GB size employee log table is running for hours.

```
select dept,count(distinct emp_id) from emp_log group by dept;
```

There are just 4-5 departments and a huge number of employees per department.

It was run with Hive 0.14 + Tez on 1TB memory. Is there any way to optimize this code block for better performance?

**Modification 1**
Tested with collect_list replacing distinct.

`SELECT dept, size(collect_list(emp_id)) nb_emps
FROM emp_log 
GROUP BY dept`

Got the below error,
`Status: Failed Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2,vertexId=vertex_1446976653619_0043_1_02, diagnostics=[Task failed,taskId=task_1446976653619_0043_1_02_000282, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Impala has large performance gains over Hive, but I assume you are using an HDP cluster. In that case, sorry to say that query looks too simple to optimize.

Comment: If not for the query... is there any hive parameter configuration which can improve the performance?

Comment: Looking at your query, it shows you are expecting duplicate emp_id under one department. If that is not the case, try removing distinct keyword and run the same sql. Distinct always degrades performance. Also, it will be better if you can paste explain plan of the query.

Comment: You should do that 1) CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS select dept,collect_list(emp_id) emps from emp_log group by dept and after that 2) SELECT * FROM foo WHERE size(emps)>1 LIMIT 5

Answer (score 0):

You should try that to avoid *count(distinct foo)* :

```
SELECT dept, size(collect_list(emp_id)) nb_emps
FROM emp_log 
GROUP BY dept
```

*count(distinct x)* is ineffective in HIVE 0.14.

Also you should activate statistics for these columns:

```
ANALYZE TABLE emp_log COMPUTE STATISTICS;
ANALYZE TABLE emp_log COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS dept, emp_id;
```

Comment: tried with collect list. But faced Out of Memory Error. Do you know any potential reason why such an error shows up when the memory is more than enough?  
  
`Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1446976653619_0043_1_02, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1446976653619_0043_1_02_000282, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`
     `

Comment: You should try with _DISTRIBUTED BY emp_id_

Answer (score 0):

Please try the test case again after increasing the following properties:

in Hive Configs:

`hive.tez.conatiner.size`

and
in Tez Configs:

1) `tez.task.resource.memory.mb`

2) `tez.task.launch.cmd-opts` -> -Xmx as 80% of `tez.task.resource.memory.mb`

3) `tez.am.resource.memory.mb`

4) `tez.am.launch.cmd-opts`  -> -Xmx as 80% of `tez.am.resource.memory.mb`

This should solve the Java Heap space problem atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Your query using count(distinct) forces a single reducer.  If you use a subquery instead you won't require a single reducer.

```
select dept, count(*) from
    (select dept, emp_id from emp_log 
     group by dept, emp_id
     ) a
group by dept;
```

This should be much faster.  Cheers!